GET Method return empty array
I just want to know what exactly the solution for this. I am using PostgreSQL and there is one row in the table. I did the following:

Drop the table in postgresql then re-run the application to create a new table based on the ProjectEntity attributes.

Re insert a row on table and re-run again the application.

I checked the Project model having the getter and setters because some of the results on the internet is to make sure there is getter and setters.


Thank you for you response. I am beginner who is practicing Spring Boot.
EDIT: Here is my schema and application.properties:
schema
Table Name: projects
link varchar(255)
project_description varchar(255)
project_name varchar(255)
source_code varchar(255)
project_id integer

application.properties
spring.application.name=portfolio
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portfolio
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Here is my Spring Boot code:
ProjectEntity.java
@Entity
@Table(name="projects")
@Data
@ToString
public class ProjectEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name= "project_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer project_id;

  @Column(name="project_name")
  private String project_name;

  @Column(name="project_description")
  private String project_description;

  @Column(name="link")
  private String link;

  @Column(name="source_code")
  private String source_code;
}

ProjectRepository.java
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<ProjectEntity, Integer> {
}

ProjectService.java
@Service
public interface ProjectService {
    Iterable<ProjectEntity> getAllProjects();
}

ProjectServiceImpl.java
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

    private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    private Project project;

    ProjectServiceImpl(ProjectRepository projectRepository) {
        this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<ProjectEntity> getAllProjects() {
        return projectRepository.findAll();
    }
}

ProjectController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/projects")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private final ProjectService projectService;

    public ProjectController(ProjectService projectService) {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Iterable<ProjectEntity> getAllProjects() {
        return projectService.getAllProjects();
    }
}

Project.java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Project {

    public Integer project_id;
    public String project_name;
    public String project_description;
    public String link;
    public String source_code;
}

The return GET request using postman or curl and checking the "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/"
[{}]


Could you show your schema/table and your application.properties

I edited the post with the application.properties and schema/table.

Seems relevant - Why JPA Buddy complains about @Data annotation over JPA Entity? though it's not clear at all where the @Data annotation in your code comes from

This is weird because I created a todo app wherein the attributes are all private model and entity. When I run the application it retrieves all the data from database. I don't know why when I created a new project it does not work.

Are there Project objects currently in your data store?
